# `A` tag is not well-formed but why?

Tags: html, validation

Firebug is showing this HTML tag as "not well-formed":

```
<a id="aHarita" target="_blank" style="margin-left: 5px;" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=40.879236,29.386641&num=1&t=h&sll=40.879132,29.386962&sspn=0.006295,0.006295&ie=UTF8&ll=40.879317,29.386641&spn=0.003022,0.006947&z=18" >
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: is there a closing </a>? did you try removing the attributes one by one to figure out whether one of them is faulty?

Comment: *(validator)* http://validator.w3.org/unicorn/#validate-by-input+task_conformance

Comment: I tried but the answer was replacement of `&` with `&amp;`. But we are writing & to separate the keys aren't we?

Comment: The `&amp;` encodes the ampersand so it's valid in the HTML. The browser will recognise the entity-encoding and decode it to a real ampersand, so that when you click on the link, you'll still just get `&` instead of `&amp;`. So your keys are still separated by a single ampersand, really, it's just written differently in HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace the `&` inside the attribute value by a [reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3) like `&amp;` or `&#38;`, so:

```
<a id="aHarita" target="_blank" style="margin-left: 5px;" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=40.879236,29.386641&amp;num=1&amp;t=h&amp;sll=40.879132,29.386962&amp;sspn=0.006295,0.006295&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=40.879317,29.386641&amp;spn=0.003022,0.006947&amp;z=18" >
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a few things wrong with that, depending on your doctype. Run the page through http://validator.w3.org to get details on the validation failures. This is a good first stop for any validation problems, and should be useful for the future.

Answer (score 2):

The `&` in the href should be html encoded: `&amp;`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have to replace & with `&amp;` in your href attribute.

Answer (score 0):

"target" is not a valid attribute for "a" tags.

Comment: Depends on the HTML version and variant.

Comment: Only if the document uses a strict doctype.